# sudo: apt-get: command not found while installing lex and ycc tools via terminal

Tags: terminal, sudo, lex, apt-get

[image_terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqFaK.png)I am trying to install Lex and Ycc Tools via Terminal on a Mac M1.Whenever I run command `sudo apt-get update` ,I am getting (**sudo: apt-get: command not found**)
what is the reason behind it.
Care to help?

Comment: `apt` is a Linux tool and you are using MacOS?  You need to use a MacOS package manager like `brew`

Comment: Should i go with brew install lex or what ? @ChrisDodd

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to install brew first -- see https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/index.html